# Is this a good way of supporting multiple authentication modes?

Tags: rest, authentication, cakephp

I'm currently working on a cakephp2 website migration and we're planning to go for a cakephp3 restful api. The website currently supports multiple authentication modes (with user-password, using a facebook account, using a google account).
Finding a restful way to do that was pretty easy for one authentication way (user-password), I rolled with cakephp's BasicAuthenticate. However, for the other authentication methods I did something like that in the AppController:

```
 public function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    // We try to get the authType and the corresponding token if they are sent as a parameter
    $authType = $this->request->getQuery('type');
    $token = $this->request->getQuery('token');
    if($token !=null) {
        switch ($authType) {
            case 'facebook':
                $this->facebookAuth($token);
                break;
            case 'google':
                $this->googleAuth($token);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm currently manually setting the user if the authentication succeeds and I was wondering if that's a "clean" way of doing it.

Comment: What version of cakephp 3 are you using?

Comment: As I said in the post, I'm using cakephp3

Comment: Again, I asked what version of cakephp 3 you are using. If you are using <3.4 then it is going to affect the answer I give you versus if it is >3.4

Comment: Oh, my bad, 3.4